# DNA result suggests my nephew is my great-nephew

Tags: dna

I had my DNA tested several years ago and was pleased with the results.  Recently I saw where my sister's son (my nephew) had apparently had his DNA tested by the same company.  While his DNA was closely the same as mine, he was identified as my "great-nephew. I am curious as to why this was the case.  I remember his mom giving birth and know of no reason for this designation.

Answer (score 2):

You may have inadvertently uncovered a family secret.

You haven't provided us with the cM for the match between you and your sister's son, but according to [DNA Painter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/860), the ranges for great-nephew (330-1467) and half nephew (492-1315) are quite similar, so he could be your half nephew instead of your great-nephew.

For him to be your great-nephew, the woman you know as your sister would be your niece. For him to be your half nephew, the woman you know as your sister would be your half sister.

Of these two situations, I think the latter is more likely. You would probably know if your sister had been born to one of your siblings instead of to your parents.

It's not uncommon for people to receive unexpected results from DNA matching.

- On this site, the answer to [Confusing DNA Ancestry](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/16329/10577) has an excellent explanation and some guidance on next steps.
- Multiple answers to [Can Ancestry.com DNA matches be wrong](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/14970/10577) contain useful information and advice.
- Ancestry has a helpful page "[Unexpected DNA Matches](https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/Unexpected-DNA-Matches?language=en_US)" that walks you through some possibilities.
- The International Society of Genetic Genealogy has an excellent [list of resources](https://isogg.org/wiki/Unexpected_results) for explanation and support.